# Restrict access of shared folder to certain network and certain user

Tags: wireless-networking, permissions, shared-folders

I have a router with local internet provider cable connected. My 2 notebooks are connected to this router through its Wi-Fi local network. I have shared access to folder at my first notebook with Windows 7 installed because I would like my second notebook to see it.

So could you please help me with the following questions:

If I will bring my first notebook to another Wi-Fi network its folder will be visible this second network, but I want it to be visible only to my first network of my router. How could I do this?

If another user comes to my first router network he will see my shared folder. How could I restrict access only for he? Or grant access only to my second notebook?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict access using Advanced sharing settings.  Take a look here;

[Windows article on folder sharing in Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/share-files-with-someone)

Failing that, [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) is an excellent open source solution for having your own FTP server and works on Windows 7 - that way you can specify very finely the level of access and control each user has - its a more granular solution to file sharing.